# "Connection to the server failed. Please try again later" error when connecting databases from 2 domains on the same server

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to connect 2 databases in my site, one from the same domain and the other from a different domain. I'm getting this error :

> Connection to the server failed. Please try again later

Both the sites are in the same server. What could the error be?

Comment: Which extension do you use? MySQLi or PDO?

Comment: i'm using mysqli

Comment: are you using "localhost" or remote address like "yourdomain.com" as host in your configuration? if you use domain as host you have to make sure that 3306 port is forwarded and remotely accessible from another domain.